# How to iterate over pixels on edge of a square in 1 iteration

Tags: java, image, geometry, coordinates

Hi is there a way of looping around the edges of a square using one for loop? The square will be aligned with the x-axis and y-axis. The square will also have a known length and center position.

Comment: It's hard to answer without having some more details e.g. code.

Comment: The answer is most likely "Yes" but we need to see your code.

Comment: so far i'm just planning the function that this is for and haven't got any code yet but the image will be a binary image in a 2d x and y array of 1's and 0's. the location of the center of the square is known and so is the distance from its center to the edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can do it in one loop, but I think you are probably looking for something like this:

```
//start at top-left
int x = center_x - (len/2);
int y = center_y - (len/2);

//point to the right
int dx=1;
int dy=0;

for (int side=0; side<4; ++side) {
    for (int i=1; i<len; ++i) {
        do_something(x,y);
        x+=dx;
        y+=dy;
    }
    //turn right
    int t=dx;
    dx=-dy;
    dy=t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work

Comment: this can be transferred to one loop but no reason to do that because the number of iterations will be the same - the number of points around the square are the same